# UITapGestureRecognizer in custom UITableViewCell within UIPicker is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am trying to implement **multiselect option** in `UIPicker` using `setAccessoryType` in `UITableViewCell` and following @[Suda's blog](http://suda.pl/multiple-row-selection-in-uipickerview/)

**Now the Problem is :** *Not getting any error but `UITapGestureRecognizer` is not getting recognized. 
`toggleSelection:` is not getting called (not able to add / remove object in `selectedItems`).*

> I have searched for this problem in SO but didn't get any solution. nothing is working for me.

I have used following code

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>
{
    NSMutableArray *selectedItems;
    NSArray *datasource;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView;
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    datasource = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", nil];
    self.pickerView.delegate = self;
    self.pickerView.dataSource = self;
    selectedItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

-(NSInteger) numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return datasource.count;
}

-(NSString*) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return datasource[row];
}

- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)view;
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [cell setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width - 20, 44)];
        cell.tag = row;
        UITapGestureRecognizer * singleTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(toggleSelection:)];
        singleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

        [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [cell addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGestureRecognizer];
        // Also tried with [cell.contentView addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGestureRecognizer];
    }
    if ([selectedItems indexOfObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:row]] != NSNotFound) {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    } else {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [datasource objectAtIndex:row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)toggleSelection:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    NSNumber *row = [NSNumber numberWithInt:recognizer.view.tag];
    NSUInteger index = [selectedItems indexOfObject:row];
    if (index != NSNotFound) {
        [selectedItems removeObjectAtIndex:index];
        [(UITableViewCell *)(recognizer.view) setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    } else { 
        [selectedItems addObject:row];
        [(UITableViewCell *)(recognizer.view) setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: What if you just add a single tap gesture recognizer to the picker view and have the tap toggle on/off the currently-selected row in the picker?

Comment: @Stonz2, I need to show check mark as its selected in picker, for that I have used UITableViewCell.

Comment: Yeah, and I think I understand what you're trying to achieve. I was just saying that instead of putting a tap gesture recognized on each cell, can you just put a single one on the picker which will toggle the check mark on the currently-selected cell (the one in the center of the picker)? Since individual cells aren't getting the action, I thought it might be a plausible workaround.

Comment: @Stonz2, If i follow your solution...Single tap wont work, because while changing the value, UITapGestureRecognizer will automatically get called in that case i will have to use double tap. but i agree your solution is half correct. thank you.